# Powerbuilder exporting to Excel R1C1 localization issue

Tags: excel, localization, powerbuilder

So I got an OleObject excel.application... and I am exporting data from the application into excel. I am using PowerBuilder 11.5. So in the excel I got Summary fields which I program setting formulas, like `aole_handle.Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]/RC[-1]".` In my case it works well. Now I send the application to the testers that are in German. They tell me that they got this message "Error calling external property in function..." when the row reaches to set the Formula. We even tried just to read the formula from that cell, like: `string ss ss = aole_handle.Selection.FormulaR1C1` and it also craches... So the question is what would be the problem... I use Microsoft Office 2010 EN, testers use the German version... if the problem is this, then how would it be it good to solve it, so the application would work independently of the office language? I have tried also:

```
aole_handle.Selection.FormulaR1C1("=RC[1]/RC[-1]")
aole_handle.Selection.Formula("=RC[1]/RC[-1]")
aole_handle.Selection.Formula = "=RC[1]/RC[-1]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel formulae are localized when given via OLE connections, thus when you have a formula like `=SUM(...)` on a French localized host you would have to send `=SOMME(...)` and with a German host `=SUMME(...)` or you get an error when setting the formula.

Similarly, the `R1C1` notation needs to be given as `Z1S1` in German. I have no German localized Excel to check, but I would suggest to test for a formula like `=ZS[1]/ZS[-1]`

Yes, this is a very annoying issue when you need to deal with foreign localized host to handle different formulae depending on the language.

Comment: I have added select case as `dim lang_code as long
lang_code = Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)`, and the applied select case statement for setting the proper translated localized formula. Even though I think that is very stupid :)

Comment: @user: so my suggestion is right and the `RC[...]` notation is actually `ZS[...]` in German?